# Alguém pode me ajuda a arrumar meu bot do whatsapp?

Tags: python

to fazendo um bot pra enviar mensagens em grupos de whatsapp ao mesmo tempo, mas ele ta dando um erro que não consigo resolver, ele abre, mas não estou conseguindo fazer a automação dele, não esta digitando nem enviando, queria saber se alguem pode me ajudar a corrigir...

Meu erro: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Meu Código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class WhatsappBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mensagem = "alo testando"
        self.grupos = ["GRUPO DA FAMÍLIA"]
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe')
    
    def EnviarMensagens(self):
        # <span dir="auto" title="GRUPO DA FAMÍLIA" class="ggj6brxn gfz4du6o r7fjleex g0rxnol2 lhj4utae le5p0ye3 l7jjieqr i0jNr">GRUPO DA FAMÍLIA</span>
        # <div tabindex="-1" class="p3_M1">
        # <span data-testid="send" data-icon="send" class="">
        self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
        time.sleep(30)
        for grupo in self.grupos:
            grupo = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='{grupo}']")
            time.sleep(3)
            grupo.click()
            chat_box = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('p3_M1')
            time.sleep(3)
            chat_box.click()
            chat_box.send_keys(self.mensagem)
            botao_enviar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="send"]')
            time.sleep(3)
            botao_enviar.click()
            time.sleep(5)

bot = WhatsappBot()
bot.EnviarMensagens()
```

Comment: Não tenho como testar aqui, mas pelo erro informado e olhando seu código, eu diria que o problema começa aqui `chat_box = self.driver.find_elements...` note que é element**s** então pode ser +1, logo deve esta retornando uma lista, mas logo abaixo vc esta usando a variável `chat_box` sem levar isso em consideração `chat_box.click()` (provavelmente a linha que disparou o erro).

Comment: aaaa entendi, sabe me informar oque eu poderia fazer pra arrumar ? eu sou novato em programação, no caso oque eu teria que fazer pra não disparar esse erro ?

Answer (score -3):

Tente isso:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class WhatsappBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mensagem = "alo testando"
        self.grupos = ["GRUPO DA FAMÍLIA"]
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = options)
    def EnviarMensagens(self):
        # <span dir="auto" title="GRUPO DA FAMÍLIA" class="ggj6brxn gfz4du6o r7fjleex g0rxnol2 lhj4utae le5p0ye3 l7jjieqr i0jNr">GRUPO DA FAMÍLIA</span>
        # <div tabindex="-1" class="p3_M1">
        # <span data-testid="send" data-icon="send" class="">
        self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com')
        time.sleep(5)
        def waiting():
            try:
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//canvas[@aria-label='Scan me!']")
            except: return False
            else: return True
    
        
        while(waiting() == True):
            print('Leia o codigo QR!')
        print('OK')    
        time.sleep(5)
        
        for grupo in self.grupos:
            grupo = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='{grupo}']")
            time.sleep(3)
            grupo.click()
            chat_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title='Mensagem']")
            time.sleep(3)
            chat_box.click()
            chat_box.send_keys(self.mensagem)
            botao_enviar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-icon="send"]')
            time.sleep(3)
            botao_enviar.click()
            time.sleep(5)

bot = WhatsappBot()
bot.EnviarMensagens()
```